# Problem with the header/ footer width

Tags: header-footer, margins, fancyhdr, incompatibility, geometry

I have recently started using the `geometry` package to format the margins of my documents. Although, I've noticed that the width of the header/ footer remains the same. How can I correct this?

Here's a `MWE`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\lhead{}
\chead{Header}
\rhead{}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{Footer}
\rfoot{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}

\begin{document}

\newgeometry{margin=0.5in, bottom=1in, top=1in}
\Blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Loading `fancyhdr` and tweaking the header/footer content must be done *after* any margin changes effected by `geometry`, so that `fancyhdr` can detect those changes. In your example, `\newgeometry` after `\begin{document}` is not needed -- simply specify the margins changes as `geometry` package options.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=0.5in,bottom=1in,top=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\lhead{}
\chead{Header}
\rhead{}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{Footer}
\rfoot{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}

\begin{document}

\Blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply lockstep. Out of curiosity, do you think there is a way to manually change a header/ footer width?

Comment: Maybe @egreg's answer is helpful in that regard.

Answer (score 7):

If you *really* need to use `\newgeometry` to change the page shape after `\begin{document}`, the recent package `titleps` can be useful:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{titleps}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\newpagestyle{jay}{%
  \sethead{}{Header}{}%
  \setfoot{}{Footer}{\thepage}%
  \setheadrule{1pt}%
  \setfootrule{1pt}%
}

\pagestyle{jay}

\begin{document}

\Blindtext

\newgeometry{margin=0.5in, bottom=1in, top=1in}

\Blinddocument

\end{document}
```

But stick to lockstep's recommendation if this change in shape is not required.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. This package seems promising.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks, I had the same problem. I used this code and by trial and error I discovered that if you put `0.005\textwith` then the text in a footer or heading is visible:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \lhead{Exam}
    \chead{}
    \rhead{Page \thepage}
    \lfoot{}
    \cfoot{}
    \rfoot{}
    \usepackage[left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
    \fancyheadoffset{0.005\textwidth}
    \begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]
    \newpage
    \lipsum[1]
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  `\fancyheadoffset{0pt}` is simpler still. However, the best thing to do is simply to load the `geometry` package _before_ calling `\pagestyle{fancy}` as in lockstep's answer.