# Change fancyhdr settings in preamble after they have already been set

Tags: header-footer, margins, fancyhdr

I have a "standard" preamble (portion in the code below that I indicated that I really don't want to change) that I am trying to reuse. But, I want to adjust the right margin for *one* particular document. There is no problem in changing the `geometry`, nor a problem in modifying the text that is placed in the header -- that works just fine. But, how do I change the location of where the header text is placed?

I want the "README" text to be right aligned with the text margin -- similar to what do not adjust the right margin -- by commenting out the line: `\geometry{right=1.0in}`

When I attempt to adjust the right margin I get the header on the right and footer page number still at the old margin location:

[image]

### Notes:

- This is not a case of needing a `newgeometry` mid way in a document. This entire document needs the slightly tweaked settings.
- This question [Problem with the header/ footer width](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40183/problem-with-the-header-footer-width)  seems to imply that `fancyhdr` must be loaded after the geometry settings, but that does not appear to be the case as the MWE below shows that the `geometry` settings after loading the `fancyhdr` package.
- An obvious solution is to just copy the preamble into a new file and change that, or add a `\def` before `\begin{document}` and only set thr right margin once, but I'd prefer to avoid those types of solutions if at all possible.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}%            
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}


% ------------- Do not want to change this from here [------
\makeatletter%
    \geometry{right=0.25in}%
    \geometry{paperheight=3.5in}% 
    \geometry{paperwidth=8.5in}%
    \geometry{showframe=true}% 
    %
    \geometry{headsep=0.25in}
    \geometry{headheight=14pt}
    \let\ps@plain\ps@fancy%
    %
    \pagestyle{fancy}% <--- Removing this gives the desired output.
    \fancyhead[R]{Don't READ}%
    \fancyfoot[R]{Page \thepage}%
\makeatother%
% ------------- Do not want to change this to here ------]

% ------------- Only want to change below here
\makeatletter%
    \geometry{right=1.0in}%
    \let\ps@plain\ps@fancy%
    %
    \pagestyle{fancy}%
    \fancyhead[R]{README}%
    \fancyfoot[R]{Page \thepage}%
\makeatother%

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `\fancyheadoffset`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}%            
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}


% ------------- Do not want to change this from here [------
\makeatletter%
    \geometry{right=0.25in}%
    \geometry{paperheight=3.5in}% 
    \geometry{paperwidth=8.5in}%
    \geometry{showframe=true}% 
    %
    \geometry{headsep=0.25in}
    \geometry{headheight=14pt}
    \let\ps@plain\ps@fancy%
    %
    \pagestyle{fancy}% <--- Removing this gives the desired output.
    \fancyhead[R]{Don't READ}%
    \fancyfoot[R]{Page \thepage}%
\makeatother%
% ------------- Do not want to change this to here ------]

% ------------- Only want to change below here
\makeatletter%
    \geometry{right=1.0in}%
    \let\ps@plain\ps@fancy%
    %
    \pagestyle{fancy}%
    \fancyheadoffset{0cm}
    \fancyhead[R]{README}%
    \fancyfoot[R]{Page \thepage}%
\makeatother%

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]